# Tried Dual Booting, now neither OS is booting up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, initramfs, busybox

I tried installing Ubuntu for the first time and I think I messed up the installation.

Now, Windows 7 is neither booting up nor it showing up as a boot option. Ubuntu is showing some CLI with busybox built-in shell written on it.

I tried re-installing windows but my hard drive is not showing up in the installation wizard, and I cannot format my hard drive except C Drive.

Any sort of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to dual booting, please follow some kind of tutorial before doing anything on your own. Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-7-ubuntu-linux-dual-boot-guide-2200653) for Win7.

**Before taking any drastic steps, check your boot menu**(you can do this by pressing F10 or F12, depends on your manufacturer). If you see anything which even remotely resembles Win7 or Ubuntu, choose that.

If nothing works, and like you said that your partitions are messed up, try the tool [GParted Live Disk](https://gparted.org/) to fix your partitions. If you know some other software that you're more comfortable with use that. **FIX YOUR PARTITIONS FIRST**.

Follow [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive) to reinstall Windows 7, and then go over the process of installing Ubuntu with the links provided before.

Comment: Sir my drive are not showing in windows installation and it is shown in ubuntu live cd but my drive on which windows was installed ,when mounted gives an error unable to access 81 gb volume. It says that ntfs is either inconsistent or hardware fault

Comment: So windows isn't booting up at all? If it shows ntfs inconsistent that means you've messed up your partitions. Do you need windows ? if yes, use some tool to fix your partitions first like GParted and reinstall windows 7( follow [this](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-clean-install-windows-7-2624917) ). If all goes well. Retry the install of Ubuntu and follow the instructions properly next time. If the answer helped, upvote and click on the tick next to the answer.

Comment: Gparted giving warning signs on all partition.On sda 3 it gives that unable to readfile system on sda 4 that 228.4 gib of unallocated space within the partition

Comment: I would suggest select all blocks sda3, sda4, etc. and changing the filesystem to ntfs. This would reformat the partitions and then you can install windows.